# Access and modify package functions called by .C() in R

Tags: c, r

I'm currently looking at the 'PlayerRatings'-package and would like to **inspect and possibly modify** the internals of the `.C("elo", ...)`-Function, which is part of this package.

I've found resources on [how to write extensions in C](http://www.math.kit.edu/stoch/~lindner/media/.c.call%20extensions.pdf), and on how to [access C-Functions of base R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html#c-find-source), but I am still unsure, where to look for the (uncompiled) source code of a **C-Function, which is part of a package in R**.

Comment: download and unpack http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/PlayerRatings_1.0-0.tar.gz and go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

- Google search CRAN + Player Ratings
- On CRAN page, click and download **[sources link](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/PlayerRatings_1.0-0.tar.gz)**
- Unpack with `tar -xvzf ./PlayerRatings_1.0-0.tar.gz` or some such
- Look at `PlayerRatings/src/ratings.c` (the `src` folder is where the C code goes).

For re-build instructions look at the how to write R extensions page you link.

Comment: This was very helpful! I should be possible to make some changes. I rechecked both linked documents, but I'm still not quite sure how to get a modified version of the function working under R. Any (general) hints? :)

Comment: General hint: rebuild the package and/or re-install the package from the locally modified source directory.

Comment: @stats-hb, `library(devtools)` can help with this.  First, remove your existing version of `PlayerRatings` (you can always re-install it later), and then navigate to the folder with your modified package, and use `devtools::install()`.  I haven't actually tried this with packages with C, but I believe it should work (though you have to have the C compilers installed on your system, etc.).  There are also ways to have dev packages and real packages co-exist without the need for removing the real package.

Comment: @stats-hb, also, you should consider looking at packages `inline` and `rcpp`.  The easiest thing for you to do might be just define a new `inline` function using the modified C code, rather than trying to rebuild a modified package.